# Inverse of a ProductUnit

Tags: java, jscience

I am trying to extend the measurements part of jscience with my own units for fuel efficiency. I defined multiple units within the units: FuelEconomy and FuelConsumption.

Example of some of the defined values:

```
public static final Unit<FuelEconomy>     KILOMETRE_PER_LITRE     = nonSI(new ProductUnit<FuelEconomy>(SI.KILOMETRE.divide(NonSI.LITRE)));
public static final Unit<FuelConsumption> LITRE_PER_KILOMETRE     = nonSI(new ProductUnit<FuelConsumption>(
                                                                NonSI.LITRE.divide(SI.KILOMETRE)));
public static final Unit<FuelConsumption> GALLON_US_PER_MILE      = nonSI(new ProductUnit<FuelConsumption>(
                                                                NonSI.GALLON_LIQUID_US.divide(NonSI.MILE)));
public static final Unit<FuelEconomy>     MILE_PER_GALLON_US      = nonSI(new ProductUnit<FuelEconomy>(
                                                                NonSI.MILE.divide(NonSI.GALLON_LIQUID_US)));
```

The problem I currently have is that I would make it possible to convert between these two ( from Km/l to l/KM ), so I want the inverse of a ProductUnit, but I get a problem that I cannot convert because the base units are different ( 1/m2 && m2 )

Am I doing something wrong in the definition of these units, or are there any other options to make this possible?

The library i am using:

http://jscience.org/experimental/javadoc/javax/measure/package-summary.html